# RCTModernEventEmitter fires twice for android fabric component

Tags: java, android, react-native, rctbridge

I am trying to create a `fabric` component for `android`, specifically I want to use the `onClickHandler` of the button component and pass a callback to `react-native` side via `RCTModernEventEmitter`. It works fine for `iOS` but for android the `RCTModernEventEmitter` emits twice every time I click the `button`

This is my spec

```
import type {HostComponent, ViewProps} from 'react-native';
import type {
  DirectEventHandler
} from 'react-native/Libraries/Types/CodegenTypes';
import codegenNativeComponent from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent';

type Event = Readonly<{
  text?: string;
}>;

interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
  text: string;
  onClickHandler?: DirectEventHandler<Event>; ////Event name should start with on
}

export default codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
  'MyButtonView',
) as HostComponent<NativeProps>;
```

On native side I have created following files

```
public class MyButtonViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<MyButtonView> {

    public static final String NAME = "MyButtonView";
    ReactApplicationContext mCallerContext;

    public MyButtonViewManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        mCallerContext = reactContext;
    }
 
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected MyButtonView createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new MyButtonView(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "text")
    public void setQrCodeText(MyButtonView view, String text) {
        view.setText(text);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants() {
        return MapBuilder.of("topOnClickHandler",
                MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onClickHandler")
        );
    }

}

public class MyButtonClickEvent extends Event<MyButtonClickEvent> {

    public MyButtonClickEvent(int viewId) {
        super(viewId);
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getEventName() {
        return "topOnClickHandler";
    }

//    @Override
//    public void dispatch(RCTEventEmitter rctEventEmitter) {
//        super.dispatch(rctEventEmitter);
//        rctEventEmitter.receiveEvent(getViewTag(), getEventName(), Arguments.createMap());
//    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchModern(RCTModernEventEmitter rctEventEmitter) {
        super.dispatchModern(rctEventEmitter);
        rctEventEmitter.receiveEvent(-1,
                getViewTag(),getEventName(),
                Arguments.createMap()
        );
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected WritableMap getEventData() {
        WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
        event.putString("message", "MyMessage");
        return event;
    }
}

public class MyButtonView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {

    public MyButtonView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        configureViews();
    }

    private void configureViews(){
        setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        setOnClickListener(view -> {
            ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();
            EventDispatcher eventDispatcher = UIManagerHelper.getEventDispatcherForReactTag(
                    reactContext ,getId()
            );
            eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new MyButtonClickEvent(getId()));
        });
    }
}
```

On `JS` side

```
<MyButtonView
  style={{height: 100, width: 100, margin: 20}}
  onClickHandler={(value: any) => {
    console.log('Hello ok bye', value.nativeEvent);
  }}
  text="Hello"
/>
```

I get `value` in `onClickHandler` of `MyButtonView` twice even though I press the `button` once

Fullrepo is here https://github.com/PritishSawant/ReactNativeFabricEventListenerExample

Edit:

I have updated my code to 0.71.1 and you can find it [here](https://github.com/PritishSawant/NewArchitectureReactNativeButtonClick0.71.1)

Comment: This would be a good github issue, have you posted it to the React Native repo?

Comment: @Abe I did post it on react's working group https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-new-architecture/discussions/65. I think I might be doing something wrong and it doesn't look to me an issue from react native's side.

Comment: @Abe I posted in to react native's repo. Is been more than 6 months but no activity https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34292

Comment: I think the only person who can help you is @SophieAlpert, Ping her.

Comment: No one replies....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting  `super.dispatchModern(rctEventEmitter);` from dispatchModern resolved the issue

Comment: I am not sure why the guy who originally suggested this removed his comment. I did ask him to put him his comment as an answer